# PySpark join on multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes, and I would like to know whether it is possible to join across multiple columns in a more generic and compact way. For example, this is a very explicit way and hard to generalize in a function:

```
df = df1.join(df2,
         on=[
              (df1.event_date < df2.risk_date)
                 &
              (df1.client_id == df2.client_id_risk)
                 &
              (df1.col_thr_param_1  == df2.col_thr_param_1)
                 &
              (df1.col_thr_param_2  == df2.col_thr_param_2)
                 &
              (df1.col_thr_param_3  == df2.col_thr_param_3)
                 &
              (df1.col_thr_param_4  == df2.col_thr_param_4)
    ], how="left"
)
```

If I have a list with the name of threshold columns that I want to join in:

thr = ["col_thr_param_1", "col_thr_param_2", "col_thr_param_3", "col_thr_param_4"]

Is it possible to pass it in a function and generalize the join? Or I always need to resort to call df1 and df2? Something like this.

```
def join_dfs(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame, thr_cols: List[str]):
   df = df1.join(df2,
           on=[
                (df1.event_date < df2.risk_date)
                   &
                (df1.client_id == df2.client_id_risk)
                   &
                **df1.thr_cols == **df2.thr_cols
           ], how="left"
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you can use alias with a list using `col()` to join. You can try something like below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def join_dfs(df1, df2, thr_cols):
  df = df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"),
           on=[
                [(F.col("df1.event_date") < F.col("df2.risk_date"))
                   ,
                (F.col("df1.client_id") == F.col("df2.client_id_risk")) ]+
                   
                [F.col(f"df1.{col}")==F.col(f"df2.{col}") for col in thr_cols]
           ], how="left"
        ) 
  return df
```